# Primitive of $x \mapsto e^{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus

To find a primitive of $x \mapsto e^{\sqrt{x}}$ I found a way but not entirely sure of that.

We have
$$D^{-1} e^{\sqrt{x}} = D^{-1} 2\sqrt{x}\cdot De^{\sqrt{x}} = D^{-1} 2\log e^{\sqrt{x}}\cdot De^{\sqrt{x}} = D^{-1}2\log u\cdot Du\bigg|_{u := e^{\sqrt{x}}}$$
and you know the rest.

The part I am unsure of is the first equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Change variable $x=y^2$, $dx=2y\,dy$. So $$I=\int e^{\sqrt x}dx=2\int y\,e^y\, dy$$ Now, use integration by part $u=y$, $v'=e^y\, dy$ so $u'=dy$, $v=e^y$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 1):

I "don't know the rest", but whatever solution you get, you can test whether it's correct by computing its derivative. If you get $e^{\sqrt{x}}$, your solution is correct. Otherwise, it isn't. You don't need our help here.

My computer algebra software gives the solution
$$ (2\sqrt{x}-1)e^{\sqrt{x}}. $$
This should differ from your solution by a constant.

Comment: Thanks so much. Indeed, splitting the last term gives the same form.